# Android Studio replaces "vertical" with "verticle" and doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android Studio I'm trying to make a scroll vertical for my buttons, when I run the code it automatically replaces android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="verticle" and gives me the error "Error:(32, 38) String types not allowed (at 'orientation' with value 'verticle')." 
I don't know what to do as it automatically replaces it when I run the code.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="verticle" >

Buttons.etc

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @user3249477 is correct. It is your quotes. Most IDEs and even StackOverflow will color code your code. Do you see how the lines in your `LinearLayout` after your first line are the wrong color? That's because you're missing an end quote.

Comment: I got it working, for some reason it was opening another manifest.xml where it would replace the code.

Comment: Did you double click on a stack trace error?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing a quote after `fill_parent`.

Also `fill_parent` is deprecated, you should use `match_parent`.